# how to access my groovy/ grails values from Javascript

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy

I have an array in my grails class

```
class BootStrap {

  def init = { servletContext ->
    def myArray = ["Aug 2011","111.0"]
    new IndexValue (indexDate: new Date (),value: 100).save(flush:true)
    assert IndexValue.count()==1
  }

  def destroy = {
  }
}
```

Now in my javascript i have this value

```
var endDate = month + ' ' + endDate.getFullYear();
```

I just need to check if this `endDate` is the same as the date in my array above, if this date is there, just give an alert `date is present`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass it as javascript variables, when you're rendering gsp, like:

```
<g:javascript>
  window.month = ${month}
</g:javascript>
```

where `month` is your grails/gsp variable